# SQL Server stored procedure update error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I have two tables

`Funddetails`:

```
 FundId  Fund   Industry State    Column1
 -----------------------------------------
     1     1        2      NSW             
     2     1        2      ACT         
     3     1        2      VIC          
     4     1        2      NSW         
     5     1        2      ACT         
     6     1        2      VIC         
     7     1        2      NSW          
     8     1        2      ACT         
     9     1        2      VIC
```

`Industrydetail`:

```
IndustryId price State
-----------------------
   1         12   NSW
   2         1    Vic
   3         3    ACT
```

I want to write a stored procedure which will update `Column1` of `funddetails` table.

`Column1` is calculated as

```
funddetails.Industry * Industrydetail.price - Avg of funddetails.Industry per state
```

If the value is less than or equal to -5 then return 50 else 100

This is my stored procedure:

```
 UPDATE FundDetails
 SET Column1 = 
        CASE 
           WHEN (funddetails.Industry * Industrydetail.price-Avg(funddetails.Industry) OVER (partition BY t2.state )) <= -5 
              THEN '50' 
              ELSE '100' 
        END
FROM FundDetails t2
INNER JOIN IndustryDetails t1 ON t1.State = t2.State
```

I am getting an error

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

I am new to SQL Server. What am I doing wrong, or is there any better approach to do what I am trying to do?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting your analytic clause in a subquery, and the `UPDATE` with `CASE` in an outer query?

Comment: Why i am given -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as below

```
UPDATE FundDetails
SET Column1= CASE 
 WHEN (funddetails.Industry*Industrydetails.price-
  (select Avg(funddetails.Industry)  OVER (partition BY FundDetails.state)) 
 <= -5 THEN '50' ELSE '100' 
 END
FROM FundDetails 
INNER JOIN Industrydetails  on FundDetails.State = Industrydetails.State
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as the below:

```
UPDATE FundDetails
SET Column1 = CASE WHEN (funddetails.Industry * t1.price- t2.MyAvg) <= -5 THEN '50' 
            ELSE '100' END
FROM 
    (SELECT fd.*, Avg(fd.Industry)  OVER (partition BY fd.state ) MyAvg FROM FundDetails fd) t2 INNER JOIN 
    IndustryDetails t1 on t1.State = t2.State 
--WHERE FundDetails.Id = t2.Id
```